# cant access element inside divs

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium C# when I click **button 1** it throws `NoSuchElementException`

I tried this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]"));

driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);

new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions
.ElementExists((By.Id("hello-button"))));
```

[![HTML is attached][1]][1]

[1]:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the button has unique [id](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_By_Id.htm), you should use it, instead of the XPath:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("hello-button")).Click();
```

Or, if it is the only button on the page

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button")).Click();
```

Comment: yes tried that as well before, gives error: : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"hello-button"}

Comment: @Nina may I ask, why do you switch frame? Are you really switching to frame `0`? Are you starting your test in different iframe? Maybe you're on wrong frame and the driver cannot locate the button.

Comment: i am just listing the different things that i tried.. As there are nested divs, i read about switching frames, so tried that as well. doesnt work... and no using frames anymore....only first line works driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]"));  which means it can go to divs. but is unable to access the button inside div.

Comment: @Nina Would it be possible to provide the url to the page?

Comment: @Nina I meant the address of the page, like https://google.com

Comment: that page is not accessible to public, thats why just gave html

Comment: Have you tried also `driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button")).Click();`?

Comment: just tried now, it gives: OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not interactable

Comment: @Nina so the button was found! It is not interactable, but that is another problem. There might be many reasons. I would check if the button is visible, with `driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button")).Displayed`. If it is false, then that means that this element has zero size.

Comment: just tried driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button")); it passed. next i tried : new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable((By.XPath(".//button"))));        and it failed with a timeout.

Comment: Clearly the element is not clickable, but for unknown reason. Maybe there is some overlay that blocks the clicking. But as I said, it is out of the scope of this issue. If my answer helped you, you can accept it :)